# How to handle frame handlers in blender python?

Tags: python, scripting, rigid-body-simulation

I've started work on my little physics sim using blender python but i'm stumped. I want my simulation to update per frame of the timeline and to stop and start when the spacebar is pressed, like the built in simulations do.

I've tried a dozen variations and keep getting error regarding nonetypes or lambda functions not having enough variables.

How do i update the mesh per frame? thanks

````
import bpy
import numpy as np

mesh_object = bpy.context.active_object

# Ensure it's a mesh and convert to numpy arrays
if mesh_object and mesh_object.type == 'MESH':
    mesh = mesh_object.data
    
    # Extract vertex coordinates as NumPy array
    #positions = np.array([v.co for v in mesh.vertices])

    length = len(mesh.vertices)
    positions = np.empty(length*3, dtype=np.float64)
    mesh.vertices.foreach_get('co', positions)
    positions.shape = (length, 3)
    
    # Extract edges as NumPy array
    #oldedges = np.array([(edge.vertices[0], edge.vertices[1]) for edge in mesh.edges])
    
    edgelength = len(mesh.edges)
    edges = np.empty(edgelength*2, dtype=np.uint8)
    mesh.edges.foreach_get('vertices', edges)
    edges.shape = (edgelength, 2)

else:
    print("Please select a valid mesh object.")


# Initialise timestep (seconds), vertex weight (kg), gravity
timestep = 0.2
weight = 0.05
gravity = np.array([0,0,-9.8])

#initialise velocities
velocities = np.zeros_like(positions)
#print(velocities)

def update(velocities, positions, timestep, weight, gravity):

    #Update velocities and positions
    velocities+= timestep*weight*gravity
    positions += timestep*velocities

    # Put it back into mesh
    positions.shape = length*3
    print(positions)
    mesh.vertices.foreach_set("co", positions)
    mesh.update()


bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_pre.append(update(velocities, positions, timestep, weight, gravity))
#bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_pre.clear()
```
````

Answer (score 1):

The `update` argument you passed in to the `frame_change_pre` handler is not callable (not a function) and therefore cannot be evaluated each time during frame change. Whatever you append to the handle should only accept one argument, which is passed in by Blender during frame change, which is the *scene*.

Here is an example script with a basic, summarized example of a working sim dependent of frame change. I included a way to have different simulations for different objects:

```
import bpy
import numpy as np


VARIABLES = dict()
TIMESTETP = 0.2
WEIGHT = 0.05
GRAVITY = np.array([0,0,-9.8])


def get_positions():
    mesh_object = bpy.context.active_object
    global VARIABLES
    # Ensure it's a mesh and convert to numpy arrays
    if mesh_object and mesh_object.type == 'MESH':
        mesh = mesh_object.data
        # Extract vertex coordinates as NumPy array
        length = len(mesh.vertices)
        positions = np.empty(length*3, dtype=np.float64)
        mesh.vertices.foreach_get('co', positions)
        positions.shape = (length, 3)
        return positions
    else:
        print("Please select a valid mesh object.")


def initialize_variables():
    global VARIABLES
    name = bpy.context.object.data.name
    mesh_dict = VARIABLES.get(name)
    # Reset only if not 'cached'
    if not mesh_dict:
        pos = get_positions()
        mesh_dict = dict(velocities = np.zeros_like(pos), positions = pos)
        VARIABLES[name] = mesh_dict


def update(scene):
    mesh = bpy.context.object.data
    # Initialize if no data has been stored for active mesh
    if not VARIABLES.get(mesh.name):
        initialize_variables()
    mesh_dict = VARIABLES[mesh.name]
    #Update velocities and positions
    mesh_dict['velocities'] += GRAVITY * (TIMESTETP * WEIGHT)
    mesh_dict['positions'] += mesh_dict['velocities'] * TIMESTETP
    # Put it back into mesh
    mesh.vertices.foreach_set("co", np.reshape(mesh_dict['positions'],len(mesh.vertices)*3))
    mesh.update()

bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_pre.append(update)
```

Comment: thanks! Why are you using a dictionary?

Comment: Am using the dictionary to store the states per mesh. An advanced way would be to save to disk using python modules like `pickle`.

Comment: ok, i think I understand. thanks again!

Comment: unfortunately this gives an error Keyerror

Comment: I've edited the code to initialize when no data is stored for selected mesh. It should clear the error.